# Print negative hex with 6 char in C

Tags: c, hex, printf, stdio

I try to print a negative number in hex and I want it to be in 6 char.
For example, `-132` in hex is `ffffff7c` and the wanted output should be `ffff7c`.

For positive number this line work:

```
fprintf(fd,"%07d \t%06x \n",i+100,instruction_data[i]);
```

for negative numbers, I get two more `f`.

Comment: I'm assuming `instruction_data[i]` is an `uint32_t`.   `%06x` will only work as you expect if the MSB is `0x00`.  As it is not (it is `0xFF`), you need to mask `instruction_data[i]` with `0xFFFFFF`.

Comment: https://tio.run/##LYtBDoIwFET3PcWkhgQiJWXDBvQi6oK0KD@RQtpiTIxnr19lVpN5b4y6GZPSjpy5r3ZAF6KluRqPQpCLmHpy@WMmW@AlwDFj7xGn5VRrfWl/09cLOCAsnus1Z1pCZk9ZQtXF39mQzKomnB0TlrDnm0KzKX6Iq3fQrXin9AE

Comment: Note that `%x` expects *unsigned* int...

Comment: @pmg Why not post it here on the site instead? I posted a community wiki based on your code below. Feel free to edit or expand it.

Comment: Thanks for making an answer from my commeent @Lundin. I'm limited to mobile and usually keep to comments for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the solution provided by @pmg in comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_hex (int val, size_t digits)
{
  char tmp[100]; 
  size_t length = sprintf(tmp, "%X", (unsigned int)val);
  if(digits > length)
  {
    digits = length;
  }
  
  printf("%.*s\n", digits, tmp+length-digits);
}

int main (void)
{
  print_hex(-132,6);   // FFFF7C
  print_hex(-132,3);   // F7C
  print_hex(-132,666); // FFFFFF7C
  print_hex(132,2);    // 84
}
```

Explanation:

- The `sprintf` call converts the passed number to ASCII hex and stores it in a temporary buffer.
- The cast to `unsigned int` is necessary for the `%X` specifier.
- `sprintf` returns the number of characters written.
- `if(digits > length) { digits = length; }` is some simple error handling to ensure that the function doesn't attempt to print more digits than present.
- The `%.*s` trick in `printf` allows the first parameter to specify how many characters to write, variably.
- `tmp+length-digits` is pointer arithmetic ensuring to print `digits` number of characters from the end of the string, rather than from the beginning, which we would have gotten if we just wrote `tmp`.

Comment: `printf("%.*s\n", digits, tmp+length-digits);` could be simplified as `printf("%s\n", tmp+length-digits);`. Furthermore the OP seems to always want 6 digits, so you should change the `sprintf(tmp, "%X", (unsigned int)val);` to `sprintf(tmp, "%.8X", (unsigned int)val);`

Answer (score 0):

To only print 6 hex digits for negative numbers on 32-bit architectures, you can simply mark the value with `0xffffff`:

```
    fprintf(fd, "%07d \t%.6x \n", i + 100, instruction_data[i] & 0xffffffU);
```

To specify the number of digits as an `int` variable:

```c
    int digits = 6;
    ...
    fprintf(fd, "%07d \t%.*x \n", i + 100, digits,
            instruction_data[i] & ~(~0U << (digits * 2) << (digits * 2)));
```